# Can't figure out how to write Regex

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to separate team names. The problem is that both teams are in one column, separated by a dash, and some teams have a dash in there name. The format is dashed team name, space, dash, space, new team name. I want to split where there is a space, followed by dash, followed by space (" - ").
For instance, here is an issue:

```
"Team-A - B"
```

I want in one column to read "Team A" and another to read "B."

To do this, I've tried

```
x <- str_split(data$Team, " - ")
```

But this just returns the same text that I sent through it. I used the regex101 link: https://regex101.com/r/PUxFir/1, and I thought I was using it correctly, but clearly not. How can I make R recognize the space before and after the dash as a distinct place to separate, and not just every dash?

Comment: Would you be able to add few rows of your data using `dput` and show expected output for it?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Jr1KbwzW. Here is a section of the vector of the dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::separate` to `split` `Team` into 2 columns.

```
tidyr::separate(df, Team, c('TeamA', 'TeamB'), sep = '\\s-\\s')

#                  TeamA                  TeamB
#1                  Bars          Torpedo Gorky
#2   Chelmet Chelyabinsk             Almetyevsk
#3  Dynamo Moscow Region              HC Rostov
#4        Gornyak Uchaly                Izhevsk
#5              HC Yugra       Nomad Nur-Sultan
#6           Krasnoyarsk        Kazzinc-Torpedo
#7               KRS ORG                  Penza
#8                Kurhan                   Perm
#9                  Orsk       Toros Neftekamsk
#10               Ryazan          Zvezda Moscow
#11               Tambov               Voronezh
#12            Tseng Tou                Beijing
#13               Tyumen              Karaganda
#14       Yermak Angarsk Metallurg Novokuznetsk
#15                 Bars          Zvezda Moscow
#16              Beijing                  Penza
#17  Chelmet Chelyabinsk       Toros Neftekamsk
#18 Dynamo Moscow Region               Voronezh
#19       Gornyak Uchaly                   Perm
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what R library you are using here, but base R's `strsplit` does in fact work with your splitting logic:

```
x <- "Team-A - B"
teams <- strsplit(x, " - ", fixed=TRUE)[[1]]
teams

[1] "Team-A" "B"
```

Comment: Tim, thank you. So I have done that, and I gave a bad example. I've had that work, but this is a vector from a dataframe. So for some reason this doest work. I added a dataframe to the reply to Ronak